# Jest Mock function is not getting called

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I have a node script which goes on like

```
const { instance } = new SDK(id, authToken);
const data = await getAllModels(instance); // helper method which uses the sdk instance to return all models
items = await getItem(instance, id);
```

I have abstracted getAllModels and getItem into a helper module inside helper.js

```
exports.getAllModels = async (instance) => {
    const { data } = await instance.getModels();
    return data;
};

exports.getItem = async (instance, zuid) => {
    const items = await instance.getItems(zuid);
    return items;
};
```

I am trying to mock both the functions in my test so that I can expect the values based on my values.

```
jest.spyOn(helper, 'getAllModels').mockImplementation(() => {
            console.log('Test');
            return Promise.resolve('c');
        });
        console.log('Test');
jest.spyOn(helper, 'getItem').mockImplementation(() => {
            console.log('Test 1');
            return Promise.resolve('d');
        });
   const baseVal = await main(instance, token);
   expect(baseVal).toBe("some value");
```

I can see that the mock values are not getting called and instead a direct call to the script is being used, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see from your code, `getAllModels` and `getItem` are named exports from `helper.js`, which you can see from the use case you posted in your first code block.

So in your test file you could have something like the following:

```js
const { getAllModels, getItem } = require('./helper');

jest.mock('./helper', () => {
  return {
    getAllModels: jest.fn(() => {
            console.log('Test');
            return Promise.resolve('c');
        }),
    getItem: jest.fn(() => {
            console.log('Test 1');
            return Promise.resolve('d');
        }),
  };
});
```

I think this is a cleaner implementation than using `spyOn` in this instance.

Comment: Hello Marcus, I can see that return value from the function I test is returning a bad expectation, to debug if I add a console log it returns response from sdk, is that expected ? I thought that it should return 'c' or 'd' as in the above snippet you shared.

Comment: uh my bad I was not returning value properly which was causing the issue. thank you for the help.

Comment: @Marcus: I have similar issue, I have a `getAllModels` function mocked the way you have answered. In some of the testes I need to redo the mock of `getAllModels` to get the different return value, and for that I am using `helper.getAllModels.mockImplementationOnce` in the test file. But the issue is that my newly added `mockImplementationOnce` is not getting called. And only the original mock is getting called. I did try it using the `spyon` but still same issue I am facing. How can I force to use the `mockImplementationOnce` version of my function?